Can you combine @Qualifier and @AliasFor in Spring?
I would like to create a qualifier annotation in Spring with multiple attributes; this part alone works as expected.
Additionally, I would like the "value" and another attribute to be aliases for each other. For this Spring offers the @AliasFor annotation.
Can both of these be combined at all? The thing is, the @AliasFor does have an effect, so Spring is clearly doing something with it. But it doesn't work; it seems to actually break the qualifier completely (break, as in, it can't find a matching bean Test bean anymore).
Below is a one-class example of how I think it should work, if it works at all. @MetaQualifier defines two attributes - value and named - as aliases of each other.
I declare a bean and qualify it via value. I request the bean qualified via either value or named. If the aliases work, both injections should work. But neither can find a matching bean. I would have expected at least the one requested via value to work.
But now comment out the @AliasFor and the injection at usageTestValue(...) suddenly works. Comment in the @Bean testNamed() and both work. (That doesn't bring me closer to my goal, but it's an interesting experiment.)
So the @AliasFor clearly has an effect, even if it doesn't seem to be a useful one. Adding other random annotations doesn't have an effect, so the effect seems to be unique to @AliasFor. If @AliasFor is not supported for qualifiers I would have expected it to have no effect at all or be treated like any other annotation, but this seems to make no sense.
Is there a way to make this work or is it doomed from the start?
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;


@Configuration
public class QualiasForTestConfig
{

  @Bean
  @MetaQualifier(value = "qualifier")
  Test testValue()
  {
    return new Test("value");
  }

//  @Bean
//  @MetaQualifier(named = "qualifier")
//  Test testNamed()
//  {
//    return new Test("named");
//  }


  @Bean
  String usageTestValue(@MetaQualifier(value = "qualifier") Test testValue)
  {
    return "Yay!";
  }

  @Bean
  String usageTestNamed(@MetaQualifier(named = "qualifier") Test testNamed)
  {
    return "Yay!";
  }

  @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Qualifier
  @Documented
  public @interface MetaQualifier
  {

    @AliasFor("named")
    String value() default "";

    @AliasFor("value")
    String named() default "";

  }

  static class Test
  {

    private final String text;


    public Test(String text)
    {
      this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return text;
    }
  }
}


If both named and value are the same (which is basically what the @AliasFor is doing) how do you expect it to work? There are 2 beans with the same qualification (due to the alias) you want 1 to be injected but which of the 2? I would actually expect an error.

There is only one active bean. The other one is commented out and only there to demonstrate that the qualifier works without any @AliasFor (as described).

One problem I see is that you define an alias for value and named but provide no link to the @Qualifier, so basically all that is taken into consideration will be the annotation itself. I also doubt you can have meta @Qualifer iwth additional properties, I don't think it is designed to do so.

You don't have to provide the value of @Qualifier. Used like this, @MetaQualifier and its attributes' values are the qualifier. It's exactly designed to do so. The added @AliasFor should - in theory - just treat value and named interchangeably.

The values aren't the qualifiers the annotation is, with further specialization. What I did notice is that if it errors out because just one of the attributes has a value and the other just the default. So this might be a bug in the merged annotations stuff (or maybe that isn't being applied to qualifier annotations).
